# Integrating Kivy and Twilio?

Tags: python-2.7, sms, kivy

Original message: I'm building a Kivy app, and I want it to send a text message. However, Kivy won't run as soon as I import the twilio.rest module. Has anyone successfully integrated Kivy and Twilio services?

Solution: Thanks to inclement for pointing me in the right direction. I needed to run this command from Terminal on the Mac to install Twilio into Kivy

$ kivy -m pip install twilio

Comment: This kind of question is best asked on kivy's irc or mailing list, where you can find users who might have done this. If you want help with the technical issues, post full details of what you do and what goes wrong (i.e. the traceback).

Comment: This is where Twilio tech support directed me to post my question. I've also posted the question to the Kivy community.

There is no traceback—my Python app simply doesn't open when I drag it onto the Kivy icon and I have the following line at the top of main.py:

from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

On the other hand, my Python app does open when I comment out the line like so:

# from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

Comment: Get the traceback. Presumably you're using the portable package (windows?), in which case possibly you can run the kivy shell directly then run your app from there (`python /path/to/app.py`) to see it. Although, since you bring up the package like this it may be that the kivy python install simply doesn't include  twilio (did you install it?) in which case, the solution is to install it. You can do the same thing to get a shell, but then run `pip install name_of_twilio_package`.

Comment: Hey A. Greyson, would you mind putting your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**: Thanks to inclement for pointing me in the right direction. I needed to run this command from Terminal on the Mac to install `Twilio` into `Kivy`

```
$ kivy -m pip install twilio
```